# Create a method applicable to a String object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to create a method applicable to a `String` object, that will return a modified `String`:

```
String s = "blabla";
String result = s.MyNewMethod();
```

I have tried to create a new class `String` but keyword `this` seems unknown:

```
class String  {

    public String MyNewMethod() {
        String s = this.Replace(',', '.'); // Replace method is unknown here
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string MyNewMethod(this string s) {
        // do something and return a string
    }
}
```

Note that extension methods are `static` and are defined in a `static` top-level class.

Answer (score 1):

I think this needs a bit more explanation.

1. String is a sealed class in .NET as in most OO typesafe languages. This means you can't subclass string. Here's some great info about strings: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html. And why they can't be subclassed.
2. To make a subclass in .net you have to use the following syntax:

   ```
   // here "Test is a subclass of Test2"
   public class Test : Test2 {

   }
   ```
3. Extension methods as mentioned by Jason are great for adding functionality to sealed classes. Extension methods can never override a function that already exists in a class. At compile time they have a lower priority then instance methods. Since extension methods do not live within the class they cannot access internal and private fields.

Comment: That they can't access internal and private fields on the class they are "extending" has nothing to do with them being `static`.

Comment: Thanks for info, that's useful. Everyday learning more and more :)